# Unable to play video which will be downloaded automatically

Tags: android, url, video, android-videoview, exoplayer

Unable to play video which will be downloaded automatically.

[http://down.okdownload8.com/20210116/8916_c122d0c0/ok夺命巨鲨HD2021.mp4](http://down.okdownload8.com/20210116/8916_c122d0c0/ok%E5%A4%BA%E5%91%BD%E5%B7%A8%E9%B2%A8HD2021.mp4)

I tried using ExoPlayer but unable to play. Tried using VideoView but at the moment unable to support url with http.

Is there any other way to play this video?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your video plays on a laptop and the video itself seems fine (tested on Mac 11.2.3 - QuickTime player 10.5).

However, I think you are seeing this problem on Android based on the tag in your question. Looking at the detail of the video using ffprobe you can see that it uses H264 'High' profile encoding:

```js
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/Users/Downloads/ok夺命巨鲨HD2021.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 01:11:03.67, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1001 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1080x458 [SAR 458:459 DAR 40:17], 930 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 90k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 64 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

While some Android devices may support this, the h264 High profile is not in the list of supported Android media types - see here:

- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats

You can verify this is the root problem if you are able to encode the video using h264 baseline or main profiles, looking at the guidelines above also, and test again on Android.